# How many plays of Pandemic Legacy until it is complete?

Tags: pandemic-legacy-season-1

I've seen and read a few spoiler-free reviews of Pandemic Legacy, and it looks great. As such I have a question I've not seen covered yet. I was wondering how many times the game is played until it is complete? I think I read somewhere that it's two plays per month - is that correct? So the game will be complete after 24 plays?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The Pandemic Legacy campaign runs over a single year. You play a game for each month, but if you lose then you play that month one more time before moving to the next one. So if you win every game, you will have 12 games, but if you lose each month then you will have 24. Before you use any of the Legacy components, you can also play an unlimited number of games of "standard" Pandemic (or something very close to it), but once you start opening packets and putting on stickers you're in for those 12-24 games.

Comment: (Just to be clear, "if you lose *the first game of each month*..." - that's how you get the most games out of the campaign.)

Comment: You are extremely unlikely to play either 12 (the game is too brutal) or 24 (its not *that* brutal) or anywhere near them - a typical range would be 16-21 games.